# UICollectionView cellForItem not called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am implementing a UICollectionView  (collectionView)  in a basic ViewController
my collection view must retrieve 5 cells as in numbersofItemInSection code.
CollectionView is showed and numbersofItemInSection  function is called but cellForItemAt function is not called so the collection view is empty.

```
import UIKit


private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"



class TestViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "test"

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews(){
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        // Configure the cell

        cell.backgroundColor = .red

        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: It does work as expected.
http://imgur.com/a/IYslT

Comment: did you use cell using xib ?

Comment: @SaurabhYadav is it possible it is my Xcode setup? Because i installed Xcode 7 yesterday, so i have 2 Xcode apps now.

Comment: @KKRocks No i did not use xib. Just UICollectionViewCell itself.

Comment: is it consits with viewcontroller in stroyboard ?

Comment: Exactly that is the issue.
Run it with xcode 8, as the syntax is for swift 3

Comment: remove         **self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)** this line and try my answer

Comment: @KKRocks i did not used storyboard. 
Must register cell for collectionView else i will have error

Comment: then how to implement cell ?

Comment: @SaurabhYadav i am actually using XcodeVersion 8.3.2 (8E2002) :(

Comment: you are mentioning that "numbersofItemInSection" has been called and in the code snippet it is not implemented! did you mean `numberOfItemsInSection` method?

Comment: yes @AhmadF i implemented numberOfItemsInSection

Comment: @zorobabel Let me check with xcode 8.3.2, i will update you.

Comment: Thanks @SaurabhYadav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your collectionView's height or collectionView's frame issue then you need set proper height to collectionView .

OR

**Try this**

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                navigationItem.title = "test"

                setupViews()
                collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
                self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) 
// remove this line if you not use xib

            }
```

Comment: You were right @KKRocks i just increase my collection view height and cells appears.

Thanks All :)

Comment: Welcome @zorobabel

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and it is working fine.As u are using swift 3 so you will have to use xCode 8+.Run it with XCODE 8, as the syntax is for swift 3 and you will get the result.